# How can I enable shift-select-mode in Emacs evil-mode non insert state

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

How can I configure Emacs so that the selection of text using shift and arrow keys in the non insert state of evil-mode becomes possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not exactly you are asking but I think this solves your problem.

Press `v` and you enter `visual-mode`. This allows you to use the arrow keys or `hjkl` to select text.